# I want to unwrap a label which has a transparent area

Tags: modeling, uv

Well, i am new to blender so this question might be easy for some to answer.
My problem, you can see on the picture.
i want unwrap the label which has a transparent area (though it is not a square).
The problem i have you can see. I want the transparent area to have same material as the glass.
Is this possible without changing the faces?
I know about baking all to single image, but i don't think the glass material would be good if i did that.
Hope I can get some advice.
[image]

**EDIT** 
I think I need attach a photo so you understand what i mean,i want to fix the edges and faces on the model so they fit the label, but how can i do ? seems like it all get distorted when i try.[image]

---

i think i need attach a photo so you understand what i mean,i want to fix the edges and faces on the model so they fit the label, but how can i do ? seems like it all get distorted when i try.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is not so much in with unwrapping but more with the material setup.

I would say your UV unwrap seems to be correct and would be suited for what you are trying to do, now all you need is to correctly setup your label material. You could do this two different ways:

1. Either copy your glass material node setup into the "Label" material node tree, and then use a *Shader Mix* node to mix the label "paper material" with the "glass material". In the mix input socket you should connect the alpha output of your image. Roughly, this:

[image]

2. Another way around is to use the same material on all faces of the bottle, including the label and glass. Use the same technique with the *Shader Mix* node setup as above, but make sure all faces have blank no UV coordinates (like setting all vertex to X0,Y0) except for the ones with the label so that the glass material shows up allover except for the parts with paper label.

**EDIT**
You an achieve this in two different ways:

1. Either model the label as a simple cylinder around the bottle with a radius slightly larger than the bottle itself like the example on the right (exaggerated radius for visibility purposes) then use alpha channel transparency in the material to hide the excess geometry. (just leave it like this, people will take care of it in their software)
2. Or model it as above and then **after** unwrapping select the top vertices and move them down using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>(double press G button) and make sure you select the *Preserve UVs* in the operator options. That way you can manually adjust the top vertices without distorting the UVs.

[image: Can]

Comment: He is using Blender Render, not Cycles.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but yeah i am using Blender Render, the thing is i want to create objects that i can share with other people for game engines and also other 3d programs, so i can export object to .obj or .fbx. I was reading about baking it all to 1 single texture from cycles but, i am not so sure that the quality of the materials will be good? i mean the glass surface will be textured instead of rendered. Or am i wrong, i am a bit confused and trying to learn about blender and 3d modeling :D.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, didn't notice what rendering engine you were using. In that case the best course of action is probably separating the label into another geometry that goes parallel and very close to the glass surface. Maybe that way it is more flexible to achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok so i need change the faces then i guess?. This is maybe a stupid question, but as i said before i just want to be able to share models in obj or fbx format (now just try to learn). I readed tutorials on baking and so on but, hard to understand everything. But if i want to make such a model of this object for example. Can i use the cycle engine and get all texture and glass on the exported model in some way? how?

Comment: If you just want to share the model for other people to use you probably don't need bother with Cycles or baking. Just make sure you provide the 3D model with the correct UV coordinates and the corresponding texture files needed for that model. In your case the label image texture you already have will suffice. Just provide the PNG and each person will then use it in it's own way to create the materials for whatever software they use it in.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, you said earlier i could "separating the label into another geometry that goes parallel and very close to the glass surface" in blender render, sorry once again for being newbie in this but how can i do that? i tried to adjust the edges on the model, when having the model unwraped (like the photo i first attached), but when i do the label ofc allso get twisted, i mean i cant really see what i am doing lol (hope you understand how i mean), sorry this is probably a basic problem to.

Comment: That is relatively simple. Select the label part of your mesh like you have in your first image, then duplicate it with Shift + D and immediately after press S to scale it outwards just a very little so it stays above the glass surface but barely so. You don't need to but you can separate it into a another object if you want to by pressing P > Selection

Comment: Edited original answer, see above for more details

Comment: Thanks any way for answering, looks like this questione turned a bit messy when i mixed everything up lol, i will make a new question.

Comment: Just noticed that it seems my answer was missing the image, check it out now

Comment: just one more question, where is "Preserve UVs"? tried find with google but no luck. Using version 2.72

Comment: It's actually called "Correct UVs", my mistake. It should show up in the operator options at the bottom of the tool shelf the lower left corner of your 3D view, press T to open the toolshelf if it's closed and you may need to scroll down or extend the panel.

Comment: Ok thanks again, i am not so sure i understand correct (again lol) the method you describe by pressing double g. I first select the vertices above the label? then press double G? Is this made on the model or the unwraped image? i try all but see no "correct uvs". Me stupid i guess lol. The first method i understand perfect, just wanted to try the other way to.

Comment: Not sure but think i figured it out, i could only use this with edge select? when i did that on model it seems to work without distorting the model. When i did it first i used the vertices select and that always distort it. Thanks again.

Comment: Have in mind that the operator options only show up after invoking the operator, so it goes like this: Go to vertex selection mode, press G+G to slide the vertex (it WILL distort the UVs) then go to the tool shelf, Search for the Vertex Slide options and tick "Correct UVs". It should remain active the next time you use it, so you only need to set it once per blender serssion

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This is a bit strange, cause if i use the "vertex select" i never get that "Correct UVs" but if i use the "edge select" i get it, and even more strange is that when i use "edge select" it dont get distorted and i dont even need to use the "Correct UVs". Its totaly possible to fix the label problem with "edge select tool" so any how i fixed the problem i had, but why is it different for you then for me?

Comment: Not sure, maybe ask a new question about it. Maybe it's a Blender version thing, I am on 2.77, what version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Ok maybe its about the versions, i use 2.72