# Custome shape Labels

Tags: modeling

I just started using a Blender. I was Maya and Keyshot user for years.

In Keyshot making, custom shape labels is 2 mins job, but how can I do it in Blender?

The problem is how to create these types of labels and wrap them on the objects, without having to model each piece of a label? Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details. Are you stuck on the modeling part or rendering?

Comment: "*In keyshot making custome shape labels is 2 mins job.*" Funny, in Blender too

Comment: @Duarte Why did you reopen this question? It currently is only an open tutorial request without a clear problem or any research.

Comment: Making a label around a bottle seems like focused enough question, even though there really doesn't seem to be any attempt on the user part to show what hes got or where he is stuck. Is this what you are looking for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52278/i-want-to-unwrap-a-label-which-has-a-transparent-area/52280#52280 ?

Comment: I am so sorry For not so clear questions. Since am only starting and trying to switch to Blender I didn't even try to make custom cut labels since I have no clue if it's possible without modeling. You helped a lot with your post. So we can use Lpha to cut out unwanted pieces. Ty so much