# Bend oval mesh around cylinder

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to blender and followed a few tutorials to learn the basics. Now i'm trying to create a beer bottle scene for one of my customers. The Neck and backside label were no problem since i could copy parts of the bottle. But the oval front label drives me crazy. I didnt get it to bend around the cylinder I've tried to follow to some bend-tutorials but im keep messing it up. I've tried the warp feature as well as the simple deform modifyer.

Does anyone know how i can achieve this:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40901/setup-for-a-wine-bottle-with-multiple-labels/40970 ?

Comment: Simple Deform modifier is a solution, but your oval has not the topology to bend, you need to create vertical edges

Comment: You need subdivisions on the object. A large face won't bend. But adding separate geometry for the label is not really necessary, when you can accomplish the same with a texture only. That way you can avoid z-fighting errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! moonboots advice worked for me. I will try it later with a textture!

Comment: as Susu says, the label can also be part of the bottle itself, you need to create a mask in the material

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52278

Answer (score 2):

You can either reate a b&w ovale image that you'll use as a mask for your bottle material, or create an object for the label itselt. In that case you can use the *Knife Project* tool:

- Create a plane, subdivide vertically. Create another object, a circle that you stretch on the Z axis and that you put in front of the plane:

[image]

- In *Object* mode, select the ovale, shift select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, go in front view and in the header menu > *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

- It has cut the ovale shape on the plane. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert the selection and delete the edges to keep the ovale:

[image]

- Apply the *Rotation* of your label, give it a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode, bend as much as you want on the Z axis, give it a *Solidify* modifier if you want:

[image]

**Or** (but it will be less accurate as it's an anamorphosis):

- Duplicate your bottle, create an circle in front of it that you stretch on the Z axis:

[image]

- Select the ovale, shift select the bottle, switch to *Edit* mode, go in front view:

[image]

- Go in the header menu > *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

- The ovale shape has been printed on the bottle, you can keep the ovale and delete the rest with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert the selection and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Faces*. Then you can give it thickness with a *Solidify* modifier.

[image]